# Using string labels in Tensorflow

Tags: python, label, tensorflow

i'am still trying to run Tensorflow with own image data. 
I was able to create a .tfrecords file with the conevert_to() function from this example [link](https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/reading_data/convert_to_records.py)

Now i i'd like to train the network with code from that example [link](https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_reader.py).

But it fails in the read_and_decode() function. My changes in that function are:

```
label = tf.decode_raw(features['label'], tf.string)
```

The Error is:

```
TypeError: DataType string for attr 'out_type' not in list of allowed values: float32, float64, int32, uint8, int16, int8, int64
```

So how to 1) read and 2) use string labels for training in tensorflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`convert_to_records.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/90121d582dbad4bd13dd2a9750c3a908e89469dd/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/convert_to_records.py) script creates a `.tfrecords` file in which each record is an [`Example`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto) protocol buffer. That protocol buffer supports string features using the [`bytes_list` kind](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/feature.proto).

The [`tf.decode_raw`](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/decode_raw) op is used to parse binary strings into image data; it is not designed to parse string (textual) labels. Assuming that `features['label']` is a `tf.string` tensor, you can use the [`tf.string_to_number`](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/string_to_number) op to convert it to a number. There is limited other support for string processing inside your TensorFlow program, so if you need to perform some more complicated function to convert the string label to an integer, you should perform this conversion in Python in the modified version of `convert_to_tensor.py`.

Comment: Is `string_to_number` just for converting _numeric_ strings to numbers, though? I get an exception for arbitrary string values (i.e. `"test"`), whereas `tf.string_to_number("20")` works fine, and yields a `20.0` `tf.float32` tensor.

Comment: Yes. If you have textual string labels and need to convert them to a number, you could use one of the [`tf.feature_column.categorical_column_*()`]
(https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column) APIs, such as [`tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list) or [`tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/categorical_column_with_hash_bucket).

Answer (score 2):

To add to @mrry 's answer, supposing your string is `ascii`, you can:

```
def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def write_proto(cls, filepath, ..., item_id): # itemid is an ascii encodable string
    # ...
    with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filepath) as writer:
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
             # write it as a bytes array, supposing your string is `ascii`
            'item_id': _bytes_feature(bytes(item_id, encoding='ascii')), # python 3
            # ...
        }))
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

Then:

```
def parse_single_example(cls, example_proto, graph=None):
    features_dict = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto,
        features={'item_id': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        # ...
        })
    # decode as uint8 aka bytes
    instance.item_id = tf.decode_raw(features_dict['item_id'], tf.uint8)
```

and then when you get it back in your session, transform back to string:

```
item_id, ... = session.run(your_tfrecords_iterator.get_next())
print(str(item_id.flatten(), 'ascii')) # python 3
```

I took the `uint8` trick from this [related so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38902908/281545). Works for me but comments/improvements welcome.

Comment: I have a TFRecord consisting of images, where one feature is the path to that image on the disk. The path is of the form `path\to\images\image432.jpg`. The length of this path varies from `88` to `91`. When I decode this particular feature as `tf.decode_raw(features['train/path'], tf.uint8)`, I get 
`ValueError: All shapes must be fully defined: [TensorShape([Dimension(None)]), TensorShape([Dimension(256), Dimension(256), Dimension(1)]), TensorShape([])]`, first dimension corresponds to the path

Comment: I'm having the same issues of all shapes needing to be fully defined. Also, I'd like to return the filename if an Assert statement is failed. Doesn't seem like this is possible.