# Include tfrecord name in exception when using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to build in some debugging code into by tensorflow dataset pipeline. Basically if tfrecord parsing fails on a certain file, I'd like to be able figure out which file that is. My dream would be to run a number of asserts in my parsing_function that provide the filename if they fail.

My pipeline looks something like this:

```
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(file_list)
        .apply(tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave(lambda f: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(f), cycle_length=4))
        .map(parse_func, num_parallel_calls=params.num_cores)
        .map(_func_for_other_stuff)
```

Ideally I'd pass the filename through in the parallel_interleave step, but if I have the anonymous function return a filename, tfrecordataset tuple, I get:

```
TypeError: `map_func` must return a `Dataset` object.
```

I've also tried to include the filename in the file itself like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084050/using-string-labels-in-tensorflow) question, but am having issues here because filenames are of variable length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of the function passed to [`tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/parallel_interleave) must be a `tf.data.Dataset`. Therefore you can solve this by attaching the filename tensor to each element of the `TFRecordDataset`, using [`tf.data.Dataset.zip()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#zip) as follows:

```
def read_records_func(filename):
  records = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename)

  # Create a dataset from the filename tensor and repeat it indefinitely.
  filename_as_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(filename).repeat(None)

  return tf.data.Dataset.zip((filename_as_dataset, records))

dataset = (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(file_list)
           .apply(tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave(read_records_func, cycle_length=4))
           .map(parse_func, num_parallel_calls=params.num_cores)
           .map(_func_for_other_stuff))
```